# Webdriver keep on executing the scenarios without terminating the job

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

I used the below **protractor cucumber multiCapabilities** config file to execute my scenarios. While executing the config file, **First time** Chrome and Firefox **got launched and my expected scenario got executed**. But after the execution the job not got finished. The webdriver keep on launching the browsers and ending with **0 scenarios / 0 steps / 0m00.000s** results. Can anyone help me to handle this situation.

Config file:

```
  exports.config = {

    seleniumAddress: "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",
    baseUrl: "https://www.google.co.in/",
    multiCapabilities: [
      {
        browserName: "chrome",
        shardTestFiles: true,
        maxInstances: 1
      },
      {
        browserName: "firefox",
        shardTestFiles: true,
        maxInstances: 1
      }
    ],

    framework: "custom",
    frameworkPath: require.resolve("protractor-cucumber-framework"),

    specs: ["../features/*.feature"],

    cucumberOpts: {    
      format: 'json:results.json',
      require: ["../stepDefinitions/*.js"],
      tags: ['@sample']
    }
  };
```

**Output:**

```
  I/launcher - 2 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
  I/testLogger -
  ------------------------------------

  I/testLogger - [chrome #01-0] PID: XXXXX
  #Expected scenario got executed      

  I/launcher - 2 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
  I/testLogger -
  ------------------------------------

  I/testLogger - [firefox #11-0] PID: XXXXX
  #Expected scenario got executed      

  I/launcher - 2 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
  I/testLogger -
  ------------------------------------

  I/testLogger - [firefox #11-1] PID: XXXXX
  [firefox #11-1] 0 scenarios
  [firefox #11-1] 0 steps
  [firefox #11-1] 0m00.000s

  I/launcher - 2 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
  I/testLogger -
  ------------------------------------

  I/testLogger - [chrome #01-1] PID: XXXXX
  [chrome #01-1] 0 scenarios
  [chrome #01-1] 0 steps
  [chrome #01-1] 0m00.000s
```

And the webdriver keep on execution the scenarios until I manually terminate the job.

Comment: How many .feature files do you have matching "../features/*.feature" pattern

Comment: Currently I'm having 8 feature files in that location. But I'm trying to access the scenarios based on the tag. And it works as expected while I used in single capabilities.